# Why is my default layout for android-studio set as linear layout?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am just starting to learn how to use the Android Studio, but as I am following the step by step guide from a book, I came to realize that the default layout is supposed to be the constraint layout. However, whenever I create a new xml file I always get a linear layout. This is my first time ever using the Android Studio program so there's no way I have somehow changed the setting by accident. How can I change the default layout back to constraint layout? I have tried the convert view option but it doesn't seem to work when trying to convert to a constraint layout. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: You need to update your Android Studio version. Use Android Studio 3.4.2 or the latest one.

Comment: I checked my version and I was using 3.4.1 so I updated to the latest version which is 3.5 but nothing seems to have changed.

Answer (score 0):

hey what happened with you bro

did you change it ?

[image: android studio]

Comment: yes instead of using convert option, if I try to choose my layout from the beginning it works. I get the same suggestions like that if I manually type in "constraint" but the thing is the default layout is set as linear layout. I cannot seem to figure out why or how it was set and I want to change the default setting.